# check two timestamp in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I am trying to join three tables where I would like to get the shipment ID where time (date and hours of a shipment) in table 2 should be less than table3. Change_Date is in the format

```
select shipment_id from table1
left join table2 on table1.shipment_id=table2.shipment_id
left join table3 on table2.shipment_id=table3.shipment_id and table2.Code=table3.Code
where table2.change_date<table3.change_date
```

Data as per below

Table1

```
shipment_id
123456
```

Table2

```
shipment_id--------------Change_Date-------------------------Code
123456------19-JAN-17 09.54.07.000000 AM----------------32
123456------19-JAN-17 10.54.07.000000 PM----------------51
```

Table3

```
shipment_id--------------Change_Date-------------------------Code
123456------19-JAN-17 12.54.07.000000 PM----------------32
123456------19-JAN-17 07.54.07.000000 AM----------------32
123456------20-JAN-17 09.54.10.000000 AM----------------32
```

So I would need the output as

```
shipemnt_id-------------Change_Date
123456--------19-JAN-17 12.54.07.000000 PM
123456--------20-JAN-17 09.54.10.000000 AM
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to retain records for a given shipment in `Table3` whose change dates are *greater* than the most recent change date for that same shipment appearing in `Table2`.  If so, then we can create a subquery which identifies the latest change date for each shipment in `Table2`, and then use that to remove records from `Table3` which we don't want to appear in our result set.

```
SELECT t1.shipment_id,
       t3.change_date
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3
    ON t1.shipment_id = t3.shipment_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT shipment_id, MAX(change_date) AS max_change_date
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY shipment_id
) t2
    ON t3.shipment_id = t2.shipment_id AND
       t3.change_date > t2.max_change_date
```